# Remove repeating mnemonic in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, fiddle

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<printArtifactGroup>
 
    <grade.content ID="I62A48BC0BA4A11DDB4B4B6752E1F6B33" legacy.identifier="008937755">
        <head.block ID="I70A39401BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639">
            <codes.head ID="I70A39402BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639" md.mnem="hg5">
                <head.info>
                    <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
                    <label.designator>1</label.designator><headtext>GENERAL</headtext>
                </head.info>
            </codes.head>
        </head.block>
    </grade.content>
        <grade.content ID="I62A48BC0BA4A11DDB4B4B6752E1F6B33" legacy.identifier="008937755">
        <head.block ID="I70A39401BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639">
            <codes.head ID="I70A39402BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639" md.mnem="hg5">
                <head.info>
                    <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
                    <label.designator>1</label.designator><headtext>GENERAL</headtext>
                </head.info>
            </codes.head>
        </head.block>
    </grade.content>
    <grade.content ID="I1A9FCF10BA4A11D" legacy.identifier="009063316">
        <head.block ID="I646E0120BA4A11DD812BA1B579905706">
            <codes.head ID="I646E0121BA4A11DD812BA1B579905706" md.mnem="hg5">
                <head.info>
                    <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
                    <label.designator>1</label.designator>
                </head.info>
            </codes.head>
            <codes.head ID="I646E2830BA4A11DD812BA1B579905706" md.mnem="hg5c">
                <head.info>
                    <headtext>GENERAL</headtext>
                </head.info>
            </codes.head>
        </head.block>
    </grade.content>
</printArtifactGroup>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<printArtifactGroup>
 
    <grade.content ID="I62A48BC0BA4A11DDB4B4B6752E1F6B33" legacy.identifier="008937755">
        <head.block ID="I70A39401BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639">
            <codes.head ID="I70A39402BA6311DD89A8F4F9961D7639" md.mnem="hg5">
                <head.info>
                    <label.name>ARTICLE</label.name>
                    <label.designator>1</label.designator><headtext>GENERAL</headtext>
                </head.info>
            </codes.head>
        </head.block>
    </grade.content>
</printArtifactGroup>
```

I want the repeating mnemonic to be removed having the same content. What will be the XSLT given template is <xsl:template match="head.block/codes.head">?

I tried something but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I really can't see what you are doing in your input/output.  You claim that you want to avoid "repeating mnemonic" which seems to mean duplicated values of the attribute ```md.mnem``` but doesn't explain what you want to do with the other data.  Also, why did the element ```codes.head``` with the attribute ```md.mnem``` of value ```hg5c``` disappear from the output?

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Perhaps include your XSL, and the criteria you want to use to group the elements